# Unsupported operand types error when code is included by function using global variables

Tags: php, include, global

I have a piece of code that work fine if I use the INCLUDE instruction of PHP. However, if inclusion is performed WITHIN another function, I get error UNSUPPORTED OPERAND TYPES on last line of included file.

Here the WORKING code

```
<?php // main.php
    unset($doc_list, $doc_idx);
    $doc_idx = 0;
    $doc_list = Array(
        'locations' => Array( 'Places', 'locations' )
    );
    include( 'nation.php' );
    $doc_list = $doc_list + Array(
        '-'.(++$doc_idx).'-' => Array( 'Town A', '' ),  
        '-'.(++$doc_idx).'-' => Array( 'Town B', '' ),
        'town_b_today' => Array( 'Today', 'locations' ),
        '-'.(++$doc_idx).'-' => Array( 'Saint-Paulet', '' )     
    );
    makeDocsFrom( 'places', $doc_list, 'site' );
?>
```

where

```
<?php // nation.php 
    $doc_list = $doc_list + Array(
        '-'.(++$doc_idx).'-' => Array( 'Nation', 'sector' ),
        'nation_today' => Array( 'Today', 'locations' )
    );
?>
```

This code gives NO error.

However, if I substitute in main.php

```
include( 'nation.php' );
```

by

```
plain_include( 'nation.php' );
```

where

```
function plain_include($file) {
    global $doc_idx, $doc_list ; // For usage inside pages  
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include($file);
    } else {
        echo '<p class="micro">Not found. URL: '.$file.'</p>';
    }
}
```

I get the following error on nation.php

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in ...nation.php on line 4
```

Note that line 4 in nation.php is

```
    );
```

Any help is appreciated. I suspect the problem is related to

```
    global $doc_idx, $doc_list ; // For usage inside pages
```

but I do not understand why.

Comment: So the sole purpose of this `plain_include` function would be to get a “nicer” error message …? That is not worth the use of globals IMHO, in all likelihood you’d be creating more problems here, than this solves.

Comment: No, the function does other things but that are not related to the problem. I just removed some instruction to make my post simpler. Of course I verified that the simplified function gives the same error, that is, that the removed instructions are not involved in error.